# C# Web Request Times Out on SSE

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient, server-sent-events

I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994417/c-sharp-http-web-request-keeps-timing-out?rq=4) question, but I am getting the response every time, it's not a closing socket issues also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41487343/c-sharp-getting-time-out-every-time-on-http-web-request) question.
I'm trying to stream from an SSE endpoint, and found [this blog](https://makolyte.com/event-driven-dotnet-how-to-consume-an-sse-endpoint-with-httpclient/) which was helpful, but I had to modify it to add a required header.

```
curl -v  http://<ip>:<port>/api/v3/ble/stream/packets -H "apikey: <key>"
```

Works and I get the streaming data.
Postman gets the 200, but no SSE data.

My C# code timesout before the response.

```
                var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, new Uri($"{APIGW_URL}/{streamingEndpoint}"));
                request.Headers.Add("apikey",APIKEY);
                request.Headers.Add("Accept", "*/*");

                logger.LogInformation("Sending request {method} to {url}:",request.Method, request.RequestUri);

                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);
                logger.LogInformation("Rescieved response with status code {statusCode} and headers :");
```

I can intercept with fiddler and see the response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Grpc-Metadata-Content-Type: application/grpc
Date: Thu, 12 Oct 2023 16:43:00 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

I've tried changing the `await` to a `.Result` or `.getAwaiter().getResult();` with no change.  I've tried different headers, but I don't think that would help because the 200 is being returned, I'm just not seeing it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding the BaseAddress to the client, which populates the host header.  It's not obvious to me why that made a difference for SSE but not for a regular get.
If someone can explain this I'll give you the answer credit.

```
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(APIGW_URL);
```